# Add SSL to Azure Portal Storage

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-storage, azureportal, azure-cdn

My website and my domain are hosted on a different service provider from azure. I created a CNAME record and I have added my custom domain to the azure. So right now I can go to `http://images.mysite.com/images/myimage.png`. The image that loads comes from the blob storage from azure. However, if I try to do this via https, I get `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error.

I've been through many guides, and seen just about every setting in azure portal and I can't figure out how to import my ssl into azure so that this will work. I have a feeling it has to do something with `Azure CDN` option, which I don't have configured and don't want to pay extra just for this one feature. Can I do this without it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

> I've been through many guides, and seen just about every setting in
>   azure portal and I can't figure out how to import my ssl into azure so
>   that this will work.

Simple answer to your question is that it is not possible as of today. Azure Storage still doesn't support HTTPS with custom domain. You'll need to use CDN if you wish to use your SSL certificates to facilitate secure connection.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name:

> Azure Storage does not yet natively support HTTPS with custom domains.
>   You can currently Use Azure CDN to access blobs by using custom
>   domains over HTTPS.

Comment: An azure function proxy would be another option depending on cost/performance requirements.